# Writing PDE in the form of convervation law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

What does one need to know in order to write $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial^3 u}{\partial x^3}=0$ in the form of a conservation law, which contains the flux? I was thinking about the Burger's equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=D\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$, where the flux $\phi = -D\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+Q(u)$, and $Q(u) = u^2$, but this does not seem "applicable enough" due to the third derivative of $u$ in the equation. I'd appreciate some hints.

Comment: Since $u u_x = \frac{1}{2} (u^2)_x$ and $u_{xxx} = (u_{xx})_x$ we can write $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} = 0$ where $\phi = \frac{u^2}{2} + \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$.